# Comparing "" and "" in C

Tags: c, string, compare, strcmp

So I have the following test code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int retVal = strcmp("", "");
  printf("%d\n", retVal);
  return 0;
}
```

And for me, it always seems print out 0, i.e. "" and "" are always equal one another. But I'm curious. Is this something guaranteed by strcmp, or does it have the potential to vary from implementation to implementation? Maybe I'm just being paranoid, but I've worked on enough strange systems to know the perils of differing implementations.

UPDATE:
I've decided to clarify to justify my paranoia. What I'm really doing in my program is more akin to this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int doOperation(const char* toCompare){
  //do stuff in here
  int compResult = strcmp(toCompare, "");
  //do more stuff depending on compResult
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  const char* myString = "";
  doOperation(myString);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to make sure things in doOperation will proceed correctly. Note that this is just an example. In my doOperation function I'm not going to actually know that the value of `toCompare`.

Comment: Why do you think that "" is different from ""?

Comment: that's a really bizarre thing to worry about...

Comment: Why would you think another system would give you a different (incorrect) answer?

Comment: You might even find that the same address is passed to `strcmp()` for each argument (though you certainly couldn't rely on that).  If you were comparing the pointers (e.g. `if ("" == "")`), then you'd be into unreliable territory; you could get different results from the same compiler with different optimization levels, let alone different compilers or different platforms.  But the string comparison with `strcmp()` is safe and anywhere that you get a result other than 0 is broken.

Comment: @BrianRoach I guess I thought some implementation somewhere just short circuit on some comparison (an "optimization"), and not even bother to actually try comparing the two string.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Yea, C can get weird and I've found the only way to combat the weirdness is to program super-defensivly. I get so paranoid when I program in C that I put on my tinfoil hat.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum - (ignoring the fact that your example uses string literals) you're passing a 2 pointers to locations in memory that contain a null terminator. Any implementation of `strcmp()` that says those are different strings is broken. I have never run across a broken `strcmp()`. I have also never found C to ever get "weird" in the last 20 years.

Comment: Don't program super defensively, that will only cause you pain. Instead, understand the weirdness when it arises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A string is equal to another string if all the characters before the NULL terminator of both strings are exactly the same. Since `""` has no characters, it fits that definition when compared with `""`.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't vary with different implementations as C code is compiled to machine specific code and `strcmp()` will do the same in all platforms.  You will get the same result everywhere.  I also agree with Seth Carnegie's answer.